# getting error "SIOCADDRT: File exists" when trying to restart network on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ip, net

Error/stdout

```
 /etc/init.d/networking restart
 * Reconfiguring network interfaces...
SIOCADDRT: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
   ...done.
```

```
netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0


ip route list
10.0.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.14  metric 1 
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0  proto static 
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0  metric 100 


/etc/network# more interfaces 
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.1.14
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.0.1.0
    broadcast 10.0.1.255
    gateway 10.0.1.1
```

```
more hosts
127.0.0.1   jenkins-server-1.bts.md  jenkins-server-1
10.0.1.14   jenkins-server-1.bts.md jenkins-server-1 # Added by NetworkManager
#127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.0.1   jenkins-server-1.bts.md  jenkins-server-1
#127.0.0.1  jenkins-server-1.bts.md  jenkins-server-1
::1 jenkins-server-1    localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
#127.0.0.1  jenkins-server-1.bts.md jenkins-server-1
#::1    jenkins-server-1    localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
#127.0.1.1  jenkins-server-1.bts.md
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
::1     jenkins-server-1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are changing the network configuration, it is normal to get such type of errors when `restarting` the network. If you are not accessing the machine remotely, you can first `stop` the network and then `start` it. If your configuration is fine, the interface(s) should be up again.

If you are still getting errors, you can try using `ifconfig` directly.

Answer (score 6):

As background information: In the context of network configuration, the `File Exists` error message is a bit misleading. What it means is that the network element you're trying to add (usually a network route) conflicts with an existing one or has already been added.

For example, you'll get this error if you try to add a "default" route if it has already been set.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the gateway had a problem.
When I restarted gateway computer, and rerun the statement:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

The error message gone and worked properly.

Comment: The accepted answer already covered this.

Comment: @chutz my answer mentions the gateway restart

Answer (score 0):

This is really silly but my network cable was unplugged... Layer 1 problems!

So check your network cable too!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/358222)

Comment: @chicks This was the answer that I came upon while troubleshooting - my response would have saved about 20 minutes of additional work. The error message does not make it obvious that a cable could be missing. No one notes that in any answer here. It's another possible solution and it's worth mentioning!